# ID mapping. Linking multiple ID's from different tables to single ID

Tags: mapping, data-mapping

Is it possible to link product id's from different tables to one universal product id? eg 1014 id from table A and 2015 id from table B to one universal 10 id in table C ?

Comment: Can you add more information to your question? What Tool/Language/... do you use?

Comment: Do you want to do this via DBMS or scripting language etc? What type of database are you using?

Answer (score 0):

In this case you could do something like this:

First your internal products:

```
master_id,  name, description, etc...
1, "Keyboard", "Nice"
2, "Mouse", "Microsoft"
3, "Monitor", "Bright"
4, "Printer", "Not the best"
```

Second table a and table b would have a master_id column that references one of those ids.

Then to select all keyboards from table a or table b:

> SELECT * FROM table_a JOIN products ON table_a.master_id =
>   products.master_id WHERE  products.master_id =1;
>
> SELECT * FROM table_b JOIN products ON table_a.master_id =
>   products.master_id WHERE  products.master_id =1;

you can then get all keyboards from BOTH tables via union:

> SELECT * FROM table_a JOIN products ON table_a.master_id =
>   products.master_id WHERE  products.master_id =1 UNION
>
> SELECT * FROM table_b JOIN products ON table_a.master_id =
>   products.master_id WHERE  products.master_id =1;

and welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: hi, i am not to fixated on the method, though it would be easier for me to do it via DBMS. am using MySQL . Sorry am relatively new to programming  so might not be as explicit.

Comment: to be exact with the need. i have uploaded details about a product and i am getting prices from different vendors regarding this product. my requirement is i need to map the product id of each vendor to my master product id. i need product name, description , details, image and all to come from the master table and only the price and URL to come from the vendor table.               Hope i am clear with my requirement ..